# Теоретический вопрос об отправлении данных, отсутствующих в локальной БД

Tags: база-данных

Приложение должно отправлять на сервер запрос для получения свежих новостей и сохранять их в локальной базе. Как сделать, чтобы сервер отправлял контент только тех новостей, которых ещё нет в локальной базе приложения? 
Мой ответ (скажите, подходит ли) - составить запрос, который будет проверять, есть ли данная новость в БД приложения или нет.

Answer (score 0):

используйте возрастающие id (обычно это у баз данных "из коробки") или временную метку. Тогда клиент отправляет на сервер свою максимальную дату или id, а сервер присылает ему разницу. Проверять все новости поштучно может быть очень долго.